# Prove that any shape 1 unit area can be placed on a tiled surface

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

Given a surface of equal square tiles where each tile side is 1 unit long. Prove that a single area A, of any shape, but just less than 1 unit square in area can be placed on the surface without touching a vertex of any tiled area? The Shape A may have holes.

Answer (score 16):

Project $A$ onto a single square by "Stacking" all of the squares in the plane.  Then translating $A$ on this square corresponds to moving $A$ on a torus with surface area one.  As the area of $A$ is less then one, there must be some point which it does not cover. Then choose that point to be the four corners of the square, and unravel the torus.

Comment: Can you explain the last step a little bit more?

Comment: Full proof can be found here: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/lattice.shtml .  I'm thinking if the area can be less than π/2: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221406

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Place $A$ randomly on the grid (consider the folding projection to just one square).