# whether any shape can be placed on a tiled surface?

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, geometry

After read "[Prove that any shape 1 unit area can be placed on a tiled surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42004/prove-that-any-shape-1-unit-area-can-be-placed-on-a-tiled-surface)",I think  on a surface of equal square tiles where each tile side is 1 unit long,the shape ,less than some constant C>1 unit square in area, can be placed on the surface without touching a vertex of any tiled area.

Is it true or false ? If it's true ,how to prove it,and how much is the constant?

Comment: Did you mean "$C < 1$"? If so, was the proof Eric Naslund gave in the linked question not enough? Or are you asking something different?

Comment: No,for C<1 it is easy to prove.

Comment: Then could you please clarify your question: Are you asking "What is the largest-area region that does not touch a vertex?"; "Is there a $C > 1$ such that every region of area at most $C$ can be rotated and translated so it does not touch a vertex?"; or something else?

Comment: Is there a C>1 such that every region of area at most C can be rotated and translated so it does not touch a vertex?  I am sorry for my poor English.I just ask it .